# Elasticsearch doesn't index something in a php application

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I've a problem using elasticsearch in a php application. The application is built with zend and uses a .env to hold the following configuration:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_MAX_DOCUMENTS=250
ELASTICSEARCH_MAX_BULK_SIZE=3M

ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=my-elasticsearch.intern.rz
ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=80
ELASTICSEARCH_USER=user
ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=pw
```

The call to index the new files is part of a import service class and looks like this:

```
public function flush(FlushInterface $flushInterface = null) {
  $bulk = $this->getSearchDocumentBulk();
  if (!empty($bulk->getActions())) {
    $response = $bulk->send();
    $this->resetSearchDocumentBulk();

    if (0 === $response->count()) {
      $data = $response->getData();
      throw new BulkException(isset($data['message']) ? strip_tags($data['message']) : '');
    }
  }

  $this->documentCache = [];

  if ($flushInterface instanceof FlushInterface) {
    $flushInterface->flush();
  }

  return $this;
}

protected function getSearchDocumentBulk() {
  if (!($this->searchDocumentBulk instanceof Bulk)) {
    $this->searchDocumentBulk = new Bulk($this->getSearchClient()->getClient());
    $this->searchDocumentBulk->setIndex(self::INDEX);
  }

  return $this->searchDocumentBulk;
}
```

I know it's only a short snippet but it's quite difficult to pull out the relevant code. So please let me know if I have to post some more methods.  
The application is started by a symfony command and I'm able to curl to elasticsearch (version 5.1) without any errors.

My problem is that no document is indexed. If I check elasticsearch-head I see that there was no data transfer anymore.  
But there's also no error, no exception or something like that. The process is completed with 100% (100,000 of 100,000 files imported). So I've no idea what happens or how to find out the bug.